# Python 3.X Writing to txt File will not create new lines

Tags: python, newline

I am trying to write multiple things to a txt file, but for some reason I cannot get each entry to end up on a new line. I have messed with placing '\n' in different spots, but the result is still the same. Below is the code being used:

```
from collections import Counter

File_1 = open('path1', 'r')
wordCounter = Counter(File_1.read().lower().replace('<p>','').replace('<p><b>','').replace('</p>','').replace('</b>','').replace('.','').replace("'",'').replace('"','').replace('<i>','').replace('</i>','').replace(',','').replace('(','').replace('-','').replace(')','').replace('<b>','').replace(';','').split())
with open('path2','w') as File_2:
    File_2.write('{:3} ==> {:15}'.format('Word','Count'))
    File_2.write('-' * 18)
    for (word,occurrence) in wordCounter.most_common():
        File_2.write('{:3} ==> {:15}'.format(word,occurrence))
File_1.close()
File_2.close()
```

Try to ignore the many replace calls, I am working with a wonky text file that needs cleaning before it can be sorted. I want each entry to appear like so:

```
Word  ==>  Count
Eighteen dashes
Entry 1 ==> # of entries
Entry 2 ==> # of entries
etc.
```

What I end up getting is:

```
Word ==> Count ------------------Entry 1 ==> # of entriesEntry 2 ==> # of entries, etc.
```

I feel like I am probably making a rookie mistake here, but is there an easy way to get the file to write each entry onto a new line? Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: You did it wrong. It's `\n`, not `/n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned, you use backslah (`\`), not forward slash (`/`).

This is your fixed code:

```
from collections import Counter
File_1 = open('path1', 'r')
wordCounter = Counter(File_1.read().lower().replace('<p>','').replace('<p><b>','').replace('</p>','').replace('</b>','').replace('.','').replace("'",'').replace('"','').replace('<i>','').replace('</i>','').replace(',','').replace('(','').replace('-','').replace(')','').replace('<b>','').replace(';','').split())
with open('path2','w') as File_2:
    File_2.write('{:3} ==> {:15}\n'.format('Word','Count'))
    File_2.write(str('-' * 18)+'\n')
    for (word,occurrence) in wordCounter.most_common():
        File_2.write('{:3} ==> {:15}\n'.format(word,occurrence))

File_1.close()
```

You also do not need to add a close for File2, since with does that for you

Comment: This was the solution, I was putting \n in the wrong places. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `print()` function with a redirection to a file.

Also, it's a good practice to use a [`with` statement](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/#motivation-and-summary) to open a file: no need to worry about the call to `close()`:

```
from collections import Counter


with open('path1', 'r') as file_1:
    wordCounter = Counter(file_1.read().lower()
                          .replace('<p>','').replace('<p><b>','')
                          .replace('</p>','').replace('</b>','')
                          .replace('.','').replace("'",'')
                          .replace('"','').replace('<i>','')
                          .replace('</i>','').replace(',','')
                          .replace('(','').replace('-','')
                          .replace(')','').replace('<b>','')
                          .replace(';','').split())

with open('path2','w') as file_2:
    print('{:3} ==> {:15}'.format('Word','Count'), file=file_2)
    print('-' * 18, file=file_2)
    for word, occurrence in wordCounter.most_common():
        print('{:3} ==> {:15}'.format(word,occurrence), file=file_2)
```

I also recommend you to follow the [PEP 8 — the Style Guide for Python Code](https://pep8.org/), where you have naming conventions explained.

**note:** to use the `print()` function with Python 2, you can use the `__future__` directive at the top of your script.

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: That doesn't answer his question. He wants to add newlines

Comment: Thank you for the information, I will look into the style guide and see where I can improve.

Comment: @PokestarFan: The `print()` function adds newlines (unless you specify `end=""`).

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE ah, i'll keep that in mind. But it's a bigger hassle though

Comment: Do you need more explanation? I suggest you to upvote and [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/344471) my answer.